# Can't orbit the center of the object after painting a single stroke

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

1."Orbit around selection" is checked.

2.Switching between another view resets the orbiting behaviour.

3.Tried in 2.81 and 2.82.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

That is what blender thinks it  is doing :)

- in object mode it orbits around selected object (as object of your interest)
- in edit mode it orbits around selected vertex
- in paint, weight, vertex, sculpt it orbits arround place of painting (like a place of your interest)

So in this case, **disable** *Orbit Around Selection* if you want to paint arround Torus. So it starts orbit around view center.

[image]

To recenter point of view select object or vertex and hit <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> or go to *3Dview Editor > View > **Frame Selected***.

[image]

If you use this operator in paint mode in will "frame" last place you paint on.

Comment: If answer worked for you consider mark answer as Solved (checkmark under vote number) so others can see it from main list. You can uncheck anytime, don't worry :)

Comment: Oh…thank you, I got it!
Didn’t realize that I need to put my mouse pointer at the center of an object before orbiting around it. Thought it as the way 3D RPGs do, how naive :)
Thank you again, very helpful!

Comment: I don't think mouse pointer matters in this case, but great it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice allows me to orbit around the entire object again.